# How can I code if I want to avoid n plus one issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these 3 models

- Student
- Gender
- BloodType
- Prefecture

Student has these three models such as Gender, BloodType, Prefecture.
and each of them belongs to Student.

Association is set up already in each model files.

In this case, how can I code if I want to avoid N + 1 issue?

Is it something like this?

```
@students = Student.find(:all).includes.includes(:gender, :blood_type, :prefecture)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `.includes` once, and you can get rid of the `find(:all)` since Rails 3 does not require it.

```
students = Student.includes(:gender, :blood_type, :prefecture)
```

Having said that, it looks like these are just look up tables and I'd recommend checking out my gem [ClassyEnum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) as a potential replacement if you are concerned about performance issues.

Comment: @Mohamad It lets you denormalize the database so there are less queries. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) explains it better than I can. The basic idea is that you eliminate the additional joins by storing the value as a string and then it's converted to an object on the fly.