# Why includes won't help to speed up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to use the gem called "bullet" in order to avoid N + 1 issue.

My previous code was

```
@communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
```

Then I was getting this errors

```
N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:platform]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:platform]

N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:genre]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:genre]

N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:tags]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:tags]
```

Then it was taking about 650ms to show a page with over 80 sql.
So I changed it to this

```
@communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC").includes(:platform, :genre, :tags)
```

Now, the alert of bullet is gone but it's taking 750ms and there are still over 80 sql.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your pagination code is wrong. It should be this:

```
@communities = Community.scoped.order("created_at DESC").paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
```

Second, it's hard to say because you don't mention if the 750ms is total execution time or just queries.

On a whim, I suspect it is because you are loading a lot of records into the memory. It could have to do with how many records your tables have, and whether you have indexed them.

I suggest you use a tool like [Miniprofiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby) to profile your page. This will help you find out exactly where your delays are.

Other things you can do assuming it's the database and not something else:

1. Add pagination to limit the result set.
2. Take a look at your logs; they have a lot of useful information.
3. Are your tables indexed? If not add indices.
4. Use Miniprofiler.

Comment: I'm running it in production mode. Also asset precompile is done. How can I add pagination to limit the result set? I thought it's fine as long as I have `page(params[:page])`

Comment: No, `params[:page]` is not going to help unless you call it on the query method. How else will Rails know what page you want?

Comment: can you check here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712893/how-can-i-code-if-i-want-to-avoid-n-plus-one-issue   Student has 3 columns. It was issuing 3 sql(To retrieve Gender,BloodType, and Prefecture) for each Student. So when it was showing 10 students, there were 30 sql queries issued. After I added `includes` it's still the same. Why? I'm checking with the gem called "bullet" and "rack-mini-profiler"

Comment: You need to add a pagination gem, like `will_paginate` then on the queries call you need to chain `paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])`

Comment: Take a look at the update I just posted. Your pagination code was not correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps. by the way, what about Kaminari pagination?

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure, I've never used it, but I can't imagine its DSL is different from `will_paginate`.

Comment: you know what? I added `per(10)` but it still issues over 80 sql